# How to set timeout for Laravel artisan

Tags: php, laravel

How to set timeout for an artisan job? And when time out the job will be killed.

I'm using Laravel 5.0 on my application.I scheduled some artisan jobs every minute in app/Console/Kernel.php.
When I grep those jobs

```
ps -ef | grep artisan
```

It seems that every job is running in separate process.

> root     23322     1  0 13:44 ?        00:00:00 xxx/php-5.5.7/bin/php artisan fetchTopic 0 10 1
>
> root     23324     1  0 13:44 ?        00:00:00 xxx/php-5.5.7/bin/php artisan fetchTopic 0 10 2
>
> root     23326     1  0 13:44 ?        00:00:00 xxx/php-5.5.7/bin/php artisan fetchComment

And when one job finish its task, the process will be killed automatically.
But it is strange that some of the processes are not killed normally. And over time, more and more strange processes are permanent which lead to CPU 100%. So I want to set an timeout for the artisan job, when time out the job will be killed automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I checked the Laravel code and there is no graceful way of killing these long artisan processes.

However you can limit overall php execution time on your own risk. You can use function [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) for this or add max_execution_time in  your php.ini

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice answer. I think this a pretty good solution at the present stage

Comment: There is no such functionality because you are responsible of coding your own stable (in terms of cpu and memory usage) commands. Of course, you can control the execution of the script following good programming practices and avoiding memory leaks by leaving a command unstably running through time.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify `max_execution_time` as an option.

Example, instead of

```
php artisan your-slow-command
```

You can use:

```
php -d max_execution_time=900 artisan your-slow-command
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and changing the value of `max_input_time` in the **cli** php.ini file lead to the desired effect.

**Example:** (`/etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini`)

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time = 99
```

Comment: It says right in the comments "Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI" changing the setting has no effect.